# comments in drupal auto width

Tags: html, css, drupal-7, width

I have 2 div blocks that programmatically follow one after the other. by default they have is the width of 900px. In order to accommodate them to the width of the text, I put the

float: left; 
or 
display: inline-block;

div gets the width of the size of the text, but the lower div slides over the top lining up in a row.
PS I have a question-and-answer page, a question - one div, another answer.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYBYI.png

Answer (score 0):

just add this to `html`

```
<div style="display:block">
    <div id="ques">Question</div>
    <div id="answer">Answer</div>
</div>
```

and this is a `css`

```
#ques{ border:1px solid #000; height:80px;width:200px; margin-bottom:20px}
#answer{border:1px solid #000; height:80px; width:200px}
```

or see ur example  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/anupkaranjkar/MrFrK/)

Comment: I need an auto-resizible div with not-static width. When question is small, div is small too, when question is large, div large too.